# restTemplate to attach a file to an event

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am generating a file, and then an event. I want to attach the file to the event generated. Thus, making use of a POST method here.

However, I get 401: Unauthorized: [no body] error

```
 private void attachBinaryToEvent(Event event, File file) throws IOException, AuthenticationException {
    String pathEvent = platform.getUrl().get()+"/event/events/{{eventId}}/binaries";
    String pathEventAttachment = pathEvent.replace("{{eventId}}", event.getId().getValue());
    
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("name", "binaryFile");
    jsonObject.addProperty("data", new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))));
    
    HttpHeaders headers = RequestAuthenticationEncoder.encode(getCredentials());
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    log.info("HEader {}", headers.get("Authorization")); //this works as i get the credentials
    HttpEntity<JsonObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject,headers);
   
    restTemplate.postForObject(pathEventAttachment, request.toString(), Event.class); //Fails here
    
    log.info("Binary file added to the event {}", event.getId().getValue());

  }
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:421)
    at com.nordex.microservice.controller.Controller.attachBinaryToEvent(Controller.java:173)
    at com.nordex.microservice.controller.Controller.fileUpload(Controller.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
...
```

---

Update:

```
HttpEntity<JsonObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject,headers);
restTemplate.postForObject(pathEventAttachment, request, Event.class);
```

gives error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asInt"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:946)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:421)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi is the issue resolved. What's the status?

Comment: Was EOD yesterday while i posted this,  I will have a look now and update

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with you converting your HttpEntity request object to string in your postforObject request. Is there any explicit reason why you are doing that. If not try once by replacing request.toString() to just request and let us know if it works. If your jsonObject needs to be a string you can do that in your request object (if you request payload needs to be a string)

```
HttpEntity<JsonObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(),headers);
   
restTemplate.postForObject(pathEventAttachment, request, Event.class); //Fails here
```

Comment: Indeed, or do not use "postForObject" if you really want to send raw JSON yourself. I wouldn't know why doing that wrong would result in a 401 though, the simplest answer is that the credentials which are used are wrong.

Comment: there is a slight possibility that he has been using the right credentials but its still not working coz his request object is nothing but a plain string :P

Comment: @VaradharajanRaghavendran the code snippet which you provided with ```(jsonObject.toString(),headers)``` does not compile

Comment: Error updated using only request